# split numbers in and store them in different files using unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file called "list.txt" which contains the following rows of numbers.

```
31056780
31909020
31092320
61093190
61094592
45090280
45902902
```

I need to now take all the rows starting with "31" and store them in another file call file31.txt take all the rows starting with "61" and store them in file61.txt, take all rows starting with "45" store it in file45.txt

file31.txt will contain.

```
31056780
31909020
31092320
```

file61.txt will contain.

```
61093190
61094592
```

file45.txt will contain.

```
45090280
45902902
```

I tried this command for all 3 but it does not do what i want it to do.

```
awk -F\" '/31*/ {print $0}' list.txt > file31   
awk -F\" '/61*/ {print $0}' list.txt > file61
awk -F\" '/45*/ {print $0}' list.txt > file45
```

Comment: Your patterns aren't anchored to the beginning of the line. So `/31*/` will match `61093190` because it has `31` inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use output redirection inside a single `awk` script. It can construct the filename by concatenating the first two characters of the line.

```
awk '{ fn = "list" substr($0, 1, 2) ".txt"; print > fn }' list.txt
```

Comment: Right and you don't even need the variable: `awk '{ print > ("list" substr($0, 1, 2) ".txt") }' list.txt`.

Comment: @EdMorton True, but it isn't as easy to understand that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep or sed to filter the lines with a matching pattern, for example:

```
sed '/^31/!d' list.txt > list31.txt
```

Or in a for loop for every number you want:

```
for n in "31" "45" "61"; do sed '/^'"$n"'/!d' list.txt > list$n.txt; done
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Or with the `r` command: `for i in 31 61 45; do sed -n '/^'$i'/w list'$i'.txt' list.txt ; done`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
awk '/^31/{print > "file31"} /^45/{print > "file45"} /^61/{print > "file61"}' file
```

Answer (score -1):

`` for i in `cat list.txt | cut -c1-2 | uniq`; do cat list.txt | grep -P ^${i} > file${i}.txt; done ``

This command works fine and is generic enough to work for all cases.

Now let's understand how it works.

`cat list.txt | cut -c1-2 | uniq`

> 31
>
> 45
>
> 61

Next we loop over these unique identifiers to create the new files using
`cat list.txt | grep -P ^${i}`

grep -P finds strings with partial match - here ^ - means that we are looking at this partial string only at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @joe - hopefully the above command could help in your case as it could be a general script.

Comment: google UUOC, deprecated backticks, quote your variables, [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), and an introductory shell programming text.